# chatter feeds: identify concrete system generated updates on accounts feed

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, feeditem

I want to identify some chatter system generated updates (on accounts feed) which appear on screen with an specific title (i.e. You don't have permission to view this task) in order to be able to delete them.

In order to do this, I tried to run some queries on developer console, both on AccountFeed object and FeedItem object. When I run he queries, I get some interesting information, but all the fields like title, content ... are just empty.

Find some example queries below:

```
SELECT Id, Body, CommentCount, ContentData, ContentDescription, ContentFileName, ContentSize, ContentType, CreatedById, CreatedDate, InsertedById, IsDeleted, LastModifiedDate, LikeCount, LinkUrl, ParentId, RelatedRecordId, SystemModstamp, Title, Type FROM FeedItem 


SELECT Id,Body, ParentId, ContentData, CommentCount, ContentDescription, ContentFileName, ContentSize, CreatedById, CreatedDate, InsertedById, IsDeleted, LastModifiedDate, LikeCount, LinkUrl, RelatedRecordId, SystemModstamp, Title, Type FROM AccountFeed
```

I would want to gather all the records with that specific text, but don't find how to filter them using SOQL.

Until now, I've been able to delete them filtering by account and then deleting each record using developer console.

What am I missing?

Thanks